# How can I adjust the positions of figure in Tex studio?

Tags: floats, positioning

I put my figures where I want them to be, but after I run them, the places of the pictures in the pdf are changed. How do I solve this problem?

Comment: The editor has nothing to do with this. What you describe is the nature of floats like `figure` and `table` and that is how it is suppose to be. Often you can cen a bit better placement using say `\begin{figure}[htp]` or `\begin{figure}[htbp]` (the `h` specifier meaning "_place here if possible_" is not part of the default setting. Then the float will go as close to here you inserted it as it can.

Comment: the only reason to use  a `figure` environment is to specify that the content may be moved to help with page breaking. so a changed position isn't a problem that is the purpose of the environment.